# How to call a PHP function from CLI?

Tags: function, call, command-line-interface, php

Let's say I have a private function `addUser()` in `function.php` that takes `$username` as an input variable and does some stuff:

```
function addUser($username) {

//do some stuff

}
```

Now I want to call this function and pass the value $username, if possible with PHP CLI. I guess that won't work from outside `function.php` since it's private, but how could I do this then?

Comment: I don't get the point with "_won't work from outside since it's private_". Can you explain what you mean? Basically the visibility of your class methods or functions has nothing to do with the context php is running in.

Answer (score 5):

```
php -r 'include("/absolute/path/to/function.php"); addUser("some user");'
```

This should work. Because you are basically executing all that code in between `'`s. And in that you can include `function.php` and, should **appropriately** call `addUser()`.

see [phpdoc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.usage.php).

Answer (score 2):

You get your command line argumenst passed in a [argv](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) array:

```
function addUser($username) {

//do some stuff

}

addUser( $argv[1] );
```

Comment: Why -1 ? SO should make it mandatory to write a comment when -1.

Comment: @JvdBerg only `argv` -> `$argv`

Comment: @JvdBerg There are only a couple of recent downvotes on your profile, which really isn't something we consider abuse. If this continues, let us know.

Comment: I'd consider using PEAR Console_Commandline http://pear.php.net/package/Console_CommandLine :-) But plain ol' $argv sure works.

Comment: @JvdBerg Thanks for the hint, I tried that with `php function.php john_doe` but now I get an error telling me `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected T_STRING, expecting T_FUNCTION`. Seems as if the function can't handle the string john_doe, but that's weird. Do you have an idea why?

Comment: @JvdBerg It's this [here](http://code.google.com/p/piwik-ldap/source/browse/trunk/LoginLdap/Controller.php) with which I want to add LDAP Users to Piwik with a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

You can use $argv.  $argv[0] = the filename, $argv[1] = first thing after filename.

I.e. php function.php "some arg"
would be addUser("some arg");

Answer (score 0):

```
function funcb()
{
    echo 'yes';
}

if (php_sapi_name() === 'cli') {
    if (count($argv) === 1) {
        echo 'See help command'.PHP_EOL;
        exit();
    }

    if (function_exists($argv[1])) {
        $func = $argv[1];
        array_shift($argv);
        array_shift($argv);
        $func(...$argv);
    }
}
```

This works for me!